# How do you combine the response from multiple requests to a single response for a client?

Tags: kong

I have read in this book called: `Kong: The king of API Gateways` that says you can compose and transform API requests and responses. It suggests that you can combine many responses into a single response so a client only needs to make a single call instead of having to make many more to have the data for a single page. This would be a great benefit to simplification of client calls.

The problem is that the book doesn't actually tell you how to do this using kong

I tried using the request and response transformers, but these only make changes to the single request or response.

Comment: I'm also interested in the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a similar solution. Could not find any using Kong. May be one option is to write a custom Plugin using Lua. I am going to try it as mentioned [here](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/2.8.x/plugin-development/)

[Edit] This might be useful as well. https://docs.konghq.com/hub/reedelk/reedelk-transformer/

Answer (score 0):

Kong can transform  your request and response by using request-transform and response-transform plugin. No where they mention to merge mutiple response to single API. You need to develop a Micro service or REST API outside Kong to achive this.

Answer (score -2):

```
It should be pretty easy
You can actually use Java Aggregation Pattern as below.Assuming you have below Response from 3 calls:
1. public class EmployeeResponse extends Response{..};
2. public class SocialSecurityNumberResponse extends Response{..};
3. public class EmployeeSalaryResponse extends Response{..} ;

Following composite Response can be constructed:
public class CompositeEmployeeResponse extends Response{
private EmployeeResponse employeeResponse;
private SocialSecurityNumberResponse socialSecurityNumberResponse;
private EmployeeSalaryResponse employeeSalaryResponse;

/*....getters/setters....**/
}
```

Comment: This is not a very helpful answer. Can you give examples using Kong?